# setSuggestionAdapter() not working with android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

I am trying to set up a custom search suggestion adapter ([as explained in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setSuggestionsAdapter(android.widget.CursorAdapter))) in my searchable activity the following way

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_result_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_result_search_widget).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    SuggestionCursorAdapter suggestionCursorAdapter = new SuggestionCursorAdapter(this, null);
    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(suggestionCursorAdapter);

    return true;
}
```

My SuggestionCursorAdapter.class looks like this:

```
public class SuggestionCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public SuggestionCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
   }

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
   }

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text2);

    String text1String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1));
    String text2String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2));

    text1.setText(text1String);
    text2.setText(text2String);
   }
}
```

This produces the following compile time **incompatible type ERROR**:

> Error: incompatible types: SuggestionCursorAdapter cannot be converted to CursorAdapter

I guess the error comes from me using `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` which is not supported by `.setSuggestionAdapter()`. So I would have to change to using `android.widget.SearchView` which I don't want to.

Does anybody have any idea how I can overcome this? Is there some alternative to `.setSuggestionAdapter()`?

Thanks for any ideas & tips!

Comment: Sounds like you've got the wrong `CursorAdapter` class imported. Make sure you're using [the support `CursorAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.html) - `import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;`.

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem, do you want to make it the answer to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support `SearchView` class uses the support `CursorAdapter` class, not the framework `CursorAdapter`. Just make sure you've got the correct one imported in your `SuggestionCursorAdapter` class.

```
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
```